# Find and replace a value in XML using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am writing a script to find, for eg: Asset_ID, multiple occurrences in an XML and replace the Asset_ID with a value received as an argument. This is just an example. I have to send many arguments and replace each value in the XML and save the XML for further processing.

The XML looks like this

```
<ADI>
   <Metadata>
      <AMS Asset_Class="package" Asset_ID="PVOD0000000010200163"   Asset_Name="Test"  Creation_Date="2010-01-11" Description="Simple" Product="HOD" Provider="AssetSource1" Provider_ID="Model" Version_Major="34" Version_Minor="1"/>
      <App_Data App="MOD" Name="Test1" Value="Test12"/>
      <App_Data App="MOD" Name="Test13" Value="TTTT"/>
   </Metadata>
   <Asset>
   <Metadata>
      <AMS Asset_Class="title" Asset_ID="PVOD1000000010200163" Asset_Name="Sample" Creation_Date="2010-01-11" Description="Docs" Product="You" Provider="Me" Provider_ID="p2" Version_Major="34" Version_Minor="1"/>
   </Metadata>
   <Asset>
</ADI>
```

The code which I wrote was not able to find the exact value. Can someone help me in this?

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
 number = 'TITL1000000000' 
 tree = ET.parse('C:\\Work\\Scripts\\Child9.xml') 
 for element in tree.findall('.//AMS'): 
    # Get the prefix alpha characters used in each section 
    prefix = element.get('Asset_ID')[:4] 
    # Set the Asset_ID to the prefix + the ID 
    element.set('Asset_ID', '{asset_number}'.format(asset_number=number)) 
    # Write Output 
    tree.write('{asset_number}.xml'.format(asset_number=number))
```

Comment: Have you done something?

Comment: @pnv... I wrote the code and it worked now.

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

number = 'TITL1000000000'

tree = ET.parse('C:\\Work\\Scripts\\Child9.xml')

for element in tree.findall('.//AMS'):
    # Get the prefix alpha characters used in each section
    #prefix = element.get('Asset_ID')[:4]

    # Set the Asset_ID to the prefix + the ID
    element.set('Asset_ID', '{asset_number}'.format(asset_number=number))
   
# Write Output
tree.write('{asset_number}.xml'.format(asset_number=number))

Comment: @Roshanr next time, never post codes in comment. Put it in question (you can always click edit link at the bottom of your question) --> select the code block --> click on `{}` at the top to make the codes highlighted properly

Comment: @pnv.. Thanks for the comment. I was thinking where the code went :)

Comment: @Roshanr what's the problem with your current code?

Comment: @pnv... I was not pointing to the incorrect node. Now i fixed it as mentioned above. It all works now.